# Not a valid command: playGenerateSecret

Tags: macos, sbt, homebrew

I would like to create an Application secret. I have already installed sbt and brew.
These are the things I have tried:

```
sbt play-generate-secret
```

```
sbt play-update-secret
```

```
sbt playGenerateSecret
```

```
sbt
playGenerateSecret
```

However, every time, I get this message:

```
WARNING: A terminally deprecated method in java.lang.System has been called
WARNING: System::setSecurityManager has been called by sbt.TrapExit$ (file:/Users/b/.sbt/boot/scala-2.12.14/org.scala-sbt/sbt/1.5.8/run_2.12-1.5.8.jar)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of sbt.TrapExit$
WARNING: System::setSecurityManager will be removed in a future release
[info] welcome to sbt 1.5.8 (Homebrew Java 17.0.1)
[info] loading project definition from /Users/b/project
[info] set current project to b (in build file:/Users/b/)
[error] Not a valid command: playGenerateSecret
[error] Not a valid project ID: playGenerateSecret
[error] Expected ':'
[error] Not a valid key: playGenerateSecret (similar: autoGeneratedProject)
[error] playGenerateSecret
[error]
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Following is what works for me.

##### Method 1:

- cd <project_root_dir>
- sbt palyGenerateSecret

##### Method 2:

- cd <project_root_dir>
- sbt
  this drops into sbt project console. You will see your project name in [].
- playGenerateSecret